# NSMutableArray for loop

Tags: ios

My for loops don't seem to be doing what I'm asking of them.  I'm trying to do a count if it's not equal to a space and the other for loop I'm trying to remove a object if it equals a space.  Neither seem to be working cause my NSLOG tell me it's still counting the spaces and also not removing them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
NSMutableArray *a1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// Take address and break into array by colon

if ([str rangeOfString:@"::"].location == NSNotFound)
{

    NSLog(@"Double Colon not found");
}
else 
{

    a1 = [[display.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]mutableCopy];
    //Separate string by colon
    NSLog(@"Separated string by colon: %@",a1);

    //count non blank segments
    for (item in a1) {
        if (item != @""){
            numofSeg = numofSeg + 1;

            needSeg = 8 - numofSeg;
            NSLog(@"%d",needSeg);
            }

    }



    while (needSeg > 0) {

        NSUInteger index = [a1 indexOfObject:@""];
        if (index != NSNotFound) {
            [a1 insertObject:@"0000" atIndex:index];
            needSeg = needSeg - 1;

        }
    }
    for (item in a1) {
        if (item == @"") {
            //remove blank spaces from list
            [a1 removeObject:item];
        }
    }
}

//Join objects back into a string separted by colon.
NSString *join = [a1 componentsJoinedByString:@":"];
NSLog(@"Join array into String: %@",join);
```

Output below.  When I join the array back together it should equal 8 segments but only 6 show.  That telling me it's counting the two spaces from when I separated the double colon.

```
2012-10-01 19:50:52.430 IPv6[1287:c07] Separated string by colon: (
2002,
0000,
"",
""
)
2012-10-01 19:50:52.432 IPv6[1287:c07] 7
2012-10-01 19:50:52.433 IPv6[1287:c07] 6
2012-10-01 19:50:52.434 IPv6[1287:c07] 5
2012-10-01 19:50:52.435 IPv6[1287:c07] 4
2012-10-01 19:50:52.435 IPv6[1287:c07] Join array into String:       2002:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000::
```

Comment: I didn't check your algorithm but I see several problems. You should compare `NSString`'s using `compare:` method not just typing `item == @""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify a mutable array while you're iterating over it. You can reverse the logic and collect the objects you want to **keep** in a separate array.

Comment: I'm so confused.  I thought by making a mutablecopy of original array to allow me to enumerate through no? a1 = [[display.text componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]mutableCopy];

Comment: I was able to make a copy of NSMutableArray and that allowed me to enumerate through with no issues.  My only last issue is removing the double colon before I join that array back together.

Comment: Oh with a copy to the array results in an immutable copy, once I used the original array it removed the double colon.  thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

First, use ‘-isEqualToString:‘ to compare strings, not ‘!=‘.

Second, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do by comparing to ‘@""‘ -- how could there be any empty strings when separating by ‘:‘ if you've already determined that there are no instances of ‘::‘? Do you mean to be looking for ‘@" "‘?

Third, the first line is a pointless allocation in light of the fact that the first thing your else clause does is assign something else to ‘a1‘.

Comment: I'm trying to start the count if it does NOT equal a space.  That way it will only count the real 4 digit items.  Doesn't != mean NOT equal?  The spaces are being created when the user adds a double colon (::).  At the beginning when the componentsSeparatedByString runs and hits that double colon it's adding a space when it separates them.  I'm using that to insert the right amount of "0000".

Comment: I changed my compare to isEqualToString like you suggested:   if (![item isEqualToString:@""]), but rsswtmr seems to be right I'm getting a error.  Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x6c438d0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack: